xrandr can't add mode to DVI monitor
i am trying to set up my resolution by using the command xrandr --newmode and i can make a new mode but can't connect him via xrandr --addmode
and i keep getting this message
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  44
  Current serial number in output stream:  45

i am new to linux(ubuntu) so i dont know how to get rid of this. I searched up internet and i dont have xorg.conf in my etc/X11.
any help is appreciated

I fixed the problem by changing Hz in cvt command

If you expand your answer it might be useful to others? As it stands, I don’t think this is enough detail for someone facing the same issue.
